# How to find a mentor during my master's program?

Tags: masters, mentoring

I'm in my first semester of three for a Master's in Financial Engineering, and I have to say that it has inspired me to learn about so many new things.  However, I'm having trouble finding any kind of mentor to really foster that inspiration.

Three of my four classes are core classes with about 90 people, so after class there are always about 10+ people competing for a prof's attention. In addition, professors seem to want us to ask TAs first when we have questions, though the TAs don't seem so willing to connect during office hours and there are a lot of people during those as well. People in general aren't super responsive to emails, and even for career events tickets will be gone by the time I open the email to RSVP.  We have seminars from people who are friends/colleagues with my academic advisor, but when I emailed him to discuss one speaker who was particularly inspiring for me, the only response was that he would let me know when office hours were.

I recognize most people are extremely busy all the time, but I'd love to create a relationship with someone like a professor who knows so much more than I do to ask questions, get career advice, or discuss what research they're doing.  I know that people don't owe me any of their time, but to be frank, I'd like to get more out of an almost $100k program than the school name.

Is this just a question of persistence and showing some kind of initiative with independent projects, or is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Is this a "taught master's"?

Comment: It is.  We have 4 classes a semester all taught by professors, recitations with TAs, and talks every so often by people in the field.

Comment: I think it's a good question but it really does not sound like your program is designed to foster one-on-one mentorship opportunities like a research-based masters might.

Comment: That makes sense and is unfortunately what I think might be the case.  I don't even care about having it be one of the professors who teach the core classes of the program or about using it for networking for a job, but instead would just like to have some higher-level discussions.  Given that the program is supposed to be highly ranked I thought it would be a bit better in that area.

Comment: Related: [getting a mentor](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/32045/getting-a-mentor?rq=1).